# Increase Pre-Populated Excel Spreadsheet by a Percentage

Tags: microsoft-excel, statistics

I have a complex spreadsheet given to me by the engineering dept.

I want to use this spreadsheet to model increases in productivity as follows:

I want to be able to insert a % value in a cell and this will in turn, increase parts of my prepopulated spreadsheet by that %.

Is there a way to do this using Excels built-in functions or do I need VBA code?

MC

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the source of the cell values.

If they are typed values, then you could use VBA to copy the adjustment percentage and PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlMultiply to a union of cells. Of course if you wanted to add 15% to the cells, you would have to put 115% in the adjustment cell. While this operation could be automated down to the point of 'sensing' a change in the adjustment cell, it would be difficult to retain the original values. This method could also be easily performed manually.

If you wanted to input 15% to add 15% to each cell, you could also use VBA to loop through the union of cells performing the maths on each cell in turn.

If the cell values you want to adjust are derived from formulas, then you could simply add on `*SUM(1, A1)` to the end of each of the cells' formulas. In this case, A1 is the cell where 15% was entered.

I would suggest putting a 'helper cell' beside each cell you want adjusted so that it doesn't matter whether the original cell value is typed or from a formula. If the 15% adjustment is in A1 and you want D5 adjusted, put this formula in E5 `=D5*SUM(1, A1)`. This retains the original value in D5. Give E5 a red background fill of something.

Comment: Thanks. The latter solution seems to be the one I need.

Comment: You might want to use a custom number format of the adjustment cell. Something like `+0%;-0%;;`